# Link aggregation on ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, lacp

I have a VM fileserver, Windows 2012R2, installed on an ESXi 6.0U3 (free version) and would like to increase the network width by adding one more NIC and using link aggreagation. Previously this fileserver was installed directly on an HP server with a NIC teaming configuration with 4 interfaces of 1Gbps, using LACP. Our switch is an HPE 1920-48G Switch JG927A, which supports LACP.

How can I configure this link aggregation scenario for 4 interfaces of 1Gbps each using LACP, in ESXi? I have to add the 4 interfaces in the same vSwitch and connect it to VM? Or, do I add an NIC to each vSwitch and then plug the 4 vSwitch into the fileserver, and then configure the NIC teaming inside Windows 2012?

Remembering that we can not use DS, because our version of ESXi is the free one that does not have DS.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is to make a LAG on your switch and to make those 4 port in your vSwitch.

Use only one vNIC in your VM, but make sure you use the integrated vmxnet3 in the VM, as it will allow bigger usage of the vNIC (10gb), as in e1000 you would be limited to 1gb

Comment: Ok. I did it. But do I need to do any kind of configuration inside de Port Group? There isa panel, caled NIC Teaming, at the Port Group configuration, with Policy Exceptions check boxes and combo boxes. Do I configure something here?